# How to auto update code via python

Tags: python, svn, github, auto-update

I have an application written in Python which runs on RPi. I want it to auto update itself by downloading the latest code into the directory where it is installed...which may vary from user to user. It will also need to run a SQL script on occasion. What is the best approach for this? How do I ensure the code downloads to the right directory?

GitHub tutorials I have seen are focused on updating the central repository. I want the reverse to occur. Is git the best tool or would SVN or a simple HTTP download from my site be better?

Comment: After a bit more research I am thinking a simple wget to fetch a zip and then use something like "sudo unzip sourcecode.zip -d /destination/dir". These could be called via os command from python. A list of SQL commands in a pickled list could also be downloaded and run first. Any thoughts on that approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments I eventually managed to get this to work using urllib.urlretrieve to download a zip and then use zipfile to unzip and overwrite.